# Account Information Link in Customer Dashboard is not working - Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, customer-account, magento2.4, customer-address

Account Information Link is not working in customer dashboard, when i click on this link then getting below error.

[image]

Comment: can you please check if you still have this error if you disable the Mirasvit_CacheWarmer extension?

Comment: Ok Thanks i am checking and then let you know.

Comment: @DianaBotean No effect, I have disable that extension but nothing effect.

Comment: sorry to hear that :( was curious if that plugin is doing something that causes the error